# Dropdown expanding in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm using dropdown in php. I have added this in html for compatibility as below and for that dropdown I'm using css as below:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
CSS:
         css1{
           -moz-border-radius-topright: 0.4em; 
           -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0.4em;
           width: 15pt;  
           height: 31px; 
           border:1px solid #ddd;
           border-left:0px solid #ddd; 
           cursor: pointer;     
           padding-bottom: 5px;
         }
```

It is expanding when I click the dropdown in all browsers but not in IE8.

Comment: IE 8 doesnt support dropdown. ,use hacks

Comment: post your html code too..!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10132588/3030434 take a look over it

Comment: <td><input type="text" id="idtext" class="textselect_form_1" readonly=""/> 
              <select name="combo"  class="css1" id="combo1" title="Select  Type" >
               <option value="0" >a </option>
               <option value="1" >b </option>
               <option value="2" >c</option> 
               <option value="3" d </option>
               <option value="4" >e </option>
               <option value="5" >f</option>
              </select>
              
             </td>