# CSS drop down menu disappears in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS drop down menu which looks fine in firefox, chrome and most versions of IE.

But in IE8 the drop down menu disappears the second you move your mouse down onto it from the top menu bar.

I've been searching for an answer to this for a while now I found this answer here on stack

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132588/2393553

And have amended my code accordingly. But I still cant get it to work :/

**Here is my CSS**

```
#navigation {
    margin-top:-15px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    z-index:9000;
}

#navigation ul {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index:9000;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#navigation li {
    float: left;
    color: #505050;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9000;
    right:0px;
    display:block;
}


#navigation li ul
{
    display: none;
    z-index: 9000;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
}

#navigation li ul.end
{
    display: none;
    z-index: 9000;
    position:relative;
    top:auto;
    right:0;
}

#navigation a
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00529f;
    padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 9000;
}

#navigation li a:hover 
{
    background: #00529f;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 9000;
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
}

#navigation li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    z-index:9000;
    left:auto;
    margin-left:0px;
}

#navigation li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: verdana;
    z-index:9000;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    margin-left:0px;
}

#navigation li:hover a 
{
    background: #00529f;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:9000;
    margin-left:0px;
}

#navigation li:hover li a:hover
{
    background: #7ca7d8;
    z-index:9000;
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

**and here is my HTML**

```
<div id = "navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>index"><?=get_content(1)?></a></li>
        <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>about"><?=get_content(2)?></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>help"><?=get_content(7)?></a></li>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>news"><?=get_content(199)?></a></li>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>about/awards/5"><?=get_content(201)?></a></li>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>about/awards/5"><?=get_content(202)?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>products"><?=get_content(1322)?></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>products/manufacturers"><?=get_content(3208)?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>services"><?=get_content(3950)?></a></li>
        <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>media"><?=get_content(1825)?></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>blog"><?=get_content(3972)?></a></li>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>media/repair_brochure/united_kingdom_aldridge"><?=get_content(1816)?></a></li>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>media/videos/"><?=get_content(505)?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>contact"><?=get_content(4)?></a>
            <ul class="end">
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>meet_the_team.php"><?=get_content(4050)?></a></li>
                <li><a href = "<?=$myroot?>find-a-branch.php"><?=get_content(4005)?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Could someone help please?

**A quick edit to inform you that When testing this using IEtester it doesnt work in IE8. It also doesnt work on a co-worker machine who has IE8 installed. However when testing it with developer tools in IE10 setting the version back to IE8 it does work. I still have no solution :/**

Comment: You need to use the child selector here to properly target your first level menu items !

Comment: @Dev'Hamz I'm not sure what you mean by child selector

Comment: Instead of "#navigation li" use "#navigation > li"

Comment: @Dev'Hamz Just tried that, but it throws it all out of whack the nav is no longer inline. I've never seen that ">" used before. I see it in the answer I mentioned now I missed it before. What does it do and why only on that one line?

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and remove the href code. It is working fine for me in IE8(i used ie developer tool to test this).

Here is the HTML i tested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
        <style>
#navigation {
margin-top:-15px;
font-size: 14pt;
z-index:9000;
}

#navigation ul {
float: right;
list-style-type: none;
z-index:9000;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

#navigation li {
float: left;
color: #505050;
position:relative;
z-index:9000;
right:0px;
display:block;
}


#navigation li ul
{
display: none;
z-index: 9000;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;
}

#navigation li ul.end
{
display: none;
z-index: 9000;
position:relative;
top:auto;
right:0;
}

#navigation a
{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #00529f;
padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
margin-left: 1px;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 9000;
}

#navigation li a:hover 
{
background: #00529f;
color:#fff;
text-decoration: none;
z-index: 9000;
margin:0px;
display:block;
}

#navigation li:hover ul 
{
display: block;
z-index:9000;
left:auto;
margin-left:0px;
}

#navigation li:hover li
{
float: none;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: left;
font-family: verdana;
z-index:9000;
border-top:1px solid #fff;
margin-left:0px;
}

#navigation li:hover a 
{
background: #00529f;
color:#fff;
z-index:9000;
margin-left:0px;
}

#navigation li:hover li a:hover
{
background: #7ca7d8;
z-index:9000;
margin-left:0px;
}

    </style>

</head>

    <body>

   <div id = "navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href = "">sdfs</a></li>
    <li><a href = "">sdfs</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "">sdfs</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">ddfsdfs</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">sdfsfsfsd</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">hdfgfd</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href = "">fhfgh</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "">hkhfjf</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href = "">lghjn</a></li>
    <li><a href = "">tyjffgh</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "">gfdhhgd</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">lhghjgjg</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">ccvcxv</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href = "">gfdfd</a>
        <ul class="end">
            <li><a href = "">fdfdfd</a></li>
            <li><a href = "">dgdfgdfgfd</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just edited my question at the bottom in bold to give a quick update about the developer tools checker :)